# How to write a custom shader in Unity 3D that lights up a specific pixel or group of pixel?

Tags: unity-game-engine, graphics, shader, hlsl

I'm making a FPS game in Unity, and I want the environment to light up as the player is shooting on his environment.
So say I have a tree. First it would be entirely black or greyish, but if I shoot somewhere, I would see some green.
To accomplish this feature, I'm using a raycast to have the impact point and so I can access any renderer of the point that the player is shooting on.
I guess the next step would be to write a custom shader to light the exact pixel that is shot. 
Do you have any idea how I could write this shader or another way of doing this effect?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

If you are using deferred rendering: [Deferred decals](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2015/02/06/extending-unity-5-rendering-pipeline-command-buffers/).

If you are using forward rendering: [Projectors](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Projector.html).

If you need some more advanced "paint-like" functionality, use render textures coupled with RaycastHit.textureCoord to get the exact UV coordinate at your ray intersection point. You can draw stuff to render textures using Graphics.Blit. Check out [this github project](https://github.com/EsProgram/InkPainter) for some inspiration on how to do this.